# Как сделать чтобы анимация вызванная :hover продолжалась до конца, независимо от положения мыши?

Tags: html, css3, svg, анимация, svg-animation

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #8e3a89;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.svg {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.sas {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-dasharray: 2550;
}

.svg:hover .sas {
  animation: animate 3s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2550;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="svg">
  <svg viewBox="0 -101 713.75189 713" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path class="sas" d="m85.085938 304.40625c-6.144532 2.882812-8.855469 10.140625-6.117188 16.34375l28.066406 60.25c1.378906 3 3.894532 5.335938 6.988282 6.488281 1.355468.492188 2.792968.746094 4.238281.746094 1.808593.015625 3.59375-.371094 5.238281-1.117187l212.054688-99.046876-19.207032 200.824219c-.371094 3.953125 1.152344 7.839844 4.109375 10.480469 9.296875 7.695312 20.882813 12.078125 32.9375 12.472656 3.324219-.003906 6.628907-.421875 9.851563-1.242187 17.214844-4.492188 30.5625-19.832031 39.667968-46.03125l83.449219-247.101563 165.273438-77.09375c48.648437-22.699218 73.71875-68.726562 56.882812-104.652344-9.554687-18.777343-27.855469-31.550781-48.773437-34.054687-23.242188-3.507813-46.996094.148437-68.105469 10.484375l-190.726563 89.433594-205.0625-80.207032c-25.824218-9.726562-46.277343-9.476562-60.621093.878907-12.035157 9.875-18.882813 24.71875-18.589844 40.285156.125 3.949219 2.113281 7.601563 5.363281 9.859375l138.082032 94.921875-79.078126 37.421875-132.601562-33.683594c-5.433594-1.335937-11.089844 1.113282-13.84375 5.988282l-33.050781 59.496093c-1.714844 3.152344-1.984375 6.894531-.738281 10.261719 1.238281 3.371094 3.871093 6.039062 7.226562 7.328125l98.167969 40.542969zm57.121093-248.09375c.734375-5.273438 3.402344-10.074219 7.488281-13.472656 7.113282-5.117188 20.085938-4.367188 37.421876 2.117187l182.617187 71.226563-83.328125 38.917968zm-112.257812 180.117188 21.703125-38.542969 127.605468 31.679687c2.75.695313 5.652344.433594 8.238282-.742187l414.75-193.71875c16.488281-8.132813 35.058594-11.09375 53.261718-8.484375 12.765626 1.175781 24.136719 8.542968 30.4375 19.707031 10.46875 22.457031-10.109374 55.261719-44.914062 71.476563l-143.695312 67.363281 8.734374-25.828125c2.207032-6.644532-1.398437-13.824219-8.042968-16.027344-6.652344-2.203125-13.828125 1.402344-16.03125 8.046875l-102.660156 305.476563c-6.113282 17.34375-13.722657 27.699218-22.203126 29.9375-5.253906 1.011718-10.691406-.019532-15.21875-2.863282l24.949219-261.953125c.652344-6.886719-4.398437-13-11.292969-13.652343-6.886718-.660157-13 4.398437-13.65625 11.285156l-3.863281 40.039062-214.054687 99.789063-17.578125-37.421875 35.167969-16.460938c4.527343-1.996094 7.445312-6.472656 7.445312-11.414062 0-4.945313-2.917969-9.421875-7.445312-11.414063zm0 0"/></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #8e3a89;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.svg {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.sas {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-dasharray: 2550;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg">
  <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 -101 713.75189 713" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path class="sas" d="m85.085938 304.40625c-6.144532 2.882812-8.855469 10.140625-6.117188 16.34375l28.066406 60.25c1.378906 3 3.894532 5.335938 6.988282 6.488281 1.355468.492188 2.792968.746094 4.238281.746094 1.808593.015625 3.59375-.371094 5.238281-1.117187l212.054688-99.046876-19.207032 200.824219c-.371094 3.953125 1.152344 7.839844 4.109375 10.480469 9.296875 7.695312 20.882813 12.078125 32.9375 12.472656 3.324219-.003906 6.628907-.421875 9.851563-1.242187 17.214844-4.492188 30.5625-19.832031 39.667968-46.03125l83.449219-247.101563 165.273438-77.09375c48.648437-22.699218 73.71875-68.726562 56.882812-104.652344-9.554687-18.777343-27.855469-31.550781-48.773437-34.054687-23.242188-3.507813-46.996094.148437-68.105469 10.484375l-190.726563 89.433594-205.0625-80.207032c-25.824218-9.726562-46.277343-9.476562-60.621093.878907-12.035157 9.875-18.882813 24.71875-18.589844 40.285156.125 3.949219 2.113281 7.601563 5.363281 9.859375l138.082032 94.921875-79.078126 37.421875-132.601562-33.683594c-5.433594-1.335937-11.089844 1.113282-13.84375 5.988282l-33.050781 59.496093c-1.714844 3.152344-1.984375 6.894531-.738281 10.261719 1.238281 3.371094 3.871093 6.039062 7.226562 7.328125l98.167969 40.542969zm57.121093-248.09375c.734375-5.273438 3.402344-10.074219 7.488281-13.472656 7.113282-5.117188 20.085938-4.367188 37.421876 2.117187l182.617187 71.226563-83.328125 38.917968zm-112.257812 180.117188 21.703125-38.542969 127.605468 31.679687c2.75.695313 5.652344.433594 8.238282-.742187l414.75-193.71875c16.488281-8.132813 35.058594-11.09375 53.261718-8.484375 12.765626 1.175781 24.136719 8.542968 30.4375 19.707031 10.46875 22.457031-10.109374 55.261719-44.914062 71.476563l-143.695312 67.363281 8.734374-25.828125c2.207032-6.644532-1.398437-13.824219-8.042968-16.027344-6.652344-2.203125-13.828125 1.402344-16.03125 8.046875l-102.660156 305.476563c-6.113282 17.34375-13.722657 27.699218-22.203126 29.9375-5.253906 1.011718-10.691406-.019532-15.21875-2.863282l24.949219-261.953125c.652344-6.886719-4.398437-13-11.292969-13.652343-6.886718-.660157-13 4.398437-13.65625 11.285156l-3.863281 40.039062-214.054687 99.789063-17.578125-37.421875 35.167969-16.460938c4.527343-1.996094 7.445312-6.472656 7.445312-11.414062 0-4.945313-2.917969-9.421875-7.445312-11.414063zm0 0">
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="2550" to="0" begin="svg.mouseover" dur="3s"/>
    </path>
  </svg>
</div>
```